# Does Nginx receives responses from down upstream server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

If an upstream server is marked as down, will Nginx still receive responses coming from it?

We are trying to implement a graceful shutdown functionality in our app, which will start sending http 500 Nginx. Nginx will mark it as down, but we still like to forward the responses back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

for handling the error in upstream itself you should specify `proxy_intercept_errors on` then after it, you can put your path to your error files like below:

```
{
  ....
    error_page      400 401 402 403 404 500 501 502 503 504 /admin/error_page.htm;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
  ...
}
```